# How to determine user is authenticated in WCF service

Tags: wcf

i am new in wcf so one question bugging me like wcf and user authentication. generally in asp.net i send user name and password and at the server end it is validated against database and if user is valid then i store some data in session and in every page i check the session and if the session exist and true is stored for that user in that session then i let the page execute otherwise i redirect user to login page. so i want to know how to implement this kind of user authentication in wcf. i want when first time user will call any method of my service then he will pass credential and if credential is fine then he can call any method of my service. please guide me how could i do it in wcf. in wcf how i can store any data in session for each user who will call my service....is there any way??

i search google and found one like http://blog.adnanmasood.com/2010/04/29/step-by-step-guide-for-authenticating-wcf-service-with-username-and-password-over-ssl/

but here anyone notice caller pass user name & password but code look like user name and password comes twice like

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(
         delegate { return true; });

     var client = new WcfServiceClient();
     GetCredentials();
     client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username;
     client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;
     Console.Write(client.GetData(1));
     client.Close();
     Console.Read();
 }
```

...but why two user name and password is coming **UserName.UserName** it looks very ugly.
give me the best idea how to authenticate users against DB when they first time call my service and once authenticated then from the next time he can call any method of my service without giving credentials.

some one told me to develop service for authenticate user.once user authenticate then service will provide some unique token id to each wcf client and client will pass that token as message header when call any method......i have no idea how to implement it and even i do not know would it be best or not. so looking for guidance and suggestion. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way of dealing with WCF authentication is to have the client program ask for username and password once (or retrieve it from a config file), and have the client program provide it for every service call. Some examples can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405740.aspx.

The alternative is to have user sessions, which are generally a bad idea. Sessions do not scale easily, there are client and server platform compatibility considerations etc...