# WCF AJAX Enabled Web Service using the ASP.NET Identity Provider (Forms Authentication) for Username and Password Authentication and Authorization

Tags: asp.net, wcf, asp.net-identity, asp.net-ajax

In an existing ASP.NET web application with the Identity Provider, using Forms Authentication, I'd like to authenticate a WCF AJAX Enabled Web Service using the user's already provided logon credentials for the site.

i.e. the WCF web service is only authenticated if the user has passed authentication for the forms website. No further authentication would be necessary for the WCF web service since it is hosted on the same web application.

The check if the user is authenticated would use the Identity framework code like

```
bool isUserAuthenticated= (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User != null) && System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

from [How to check user is "logged in"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086529/how-to-check-user-is-logged-in)

The server-service code should be able to get the user's username from

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()
```

from
[ASP.NET MVC 5 - Identity. How to get current ApplicationUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925822/asp-net-mvc-5-identity-how-to-get-current-applicationuser)

The context for a WCF web service is OperationContext, not HttpContext.

Comment: If I understand you correctly your question is does wcf web services still need to be authenticated after they have been authenticated by ASP.NET.

Comment: Yes, I believe they do.

Comment: You can take a look at [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093765/how-to-determine-user-is-authenticated-in-wcf-service). The solution may be helpful to you.